# eclipse kepler - An internal error occurred during: "JSP Index Manager: Processing Resource Events". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I am getting the following error while starting eclipse Kepler.

**An internal error occurred during: "JSP Index Manager: Processing Resource Events".
java.lang.NullPointerException**

Do you know what can be the cause of this problem?

More details:

**Severity:** Error

**Message:** An internal error occurred during: "JSP Index Manager: Processing Resource Events".

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.indexing.AbstractIndexManager$ResourceEventProcessingJob.run(AbstractIndexManager.java:1520)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

**Session Data:**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Comment: Is it consistently happening?  Sporadically?  Just the one time?

Comment: Hi it was happening consistently. The behavior changed after creating a new workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Kepler SR1.  It's a known (and fixed) bug, http://bugs.eclipse.org/402541 .